# Correct way to create a table that references variables from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have these relationships:

`User(uid:integer,uname:varchar)`, key is uid
`Recipe(rid:integer,content:text)`, key is rid
`Rating(rid:integer, uid:integer, rating:integer)` , key is (uid,rid).

I built the table in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
    uname VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Recipes(
    rid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    content VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

Now for the `Rating` table: I want it to be impossible to insert a `uid\rid` that does not exist in `User\Recipe`.
My question is: which of the following is the correct way to do it? Or please suggest the correct way if none of them are correct. Moreover, I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me what is the difference between the two.

First:

```
CREATE TABLE Rating(
    rid INTEGER,
    uid INTEGER,
    rating INTEGER CHECK (0<=rating and rating<=5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(rid,uid),
    FOREIGN KEY (rid) REFERENCES Recipes,
    FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES User
);
```

Second:

```
  CREATE TABLE Rating(
      rid INTEGER REFERENCES Recipes,
      uid INTEGER REFERENCES User,
      rating INTEGER CHECK (0<=rating and rating<=5) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(rid,uid)
  );
```

EDIT:
I think `User` is problematic as a name for a table so ignore the name.

Comment: Which db?  If this is SQL Server, the foreign key constraint will take care of it for you.

Comment: i edited the tags.. using pl/pgsql

Comment: [`PL/pgSQL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) is the default procedural language for the PostgreSQL database system. You mean `PostgreSQL`. Your question is about database-design and does not concern pl/pgsql at all. Edited tags accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically both versions are the same in Postgres. The docs for [CREATE TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-createtable.html) say so quite clearly:

> There are two ways to define constraints: table constraints and column constraints. A column constraint is defined as part of a column definition. A table constraint definition is not tied to a particular column, and it can encompass more than one column. Every column constraint can also be written as a table constraint; a column constraint is only a notational convenience for use when the constraint only affects one column.

So when you have to reference a compound key a table constraint is the only way to go.

But for every other case I prefer the shortest and most concise form where I don't need to give names to stuff I'm not really interested in. So my version would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE usr(
    uid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
    uname TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE recipes(
    rid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    content TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE rating(
    rid INTEGER REFERENCES recipes,
    uid INTEGER REFERENCES usr,
    rating INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (rating between 0 and 5),
    PRIMARY KEY(rid,uid)
);
```

Comment: +1 for concise syntax. I dislike mixed case identifiers because they are misleading, but for the purpose of referencing the question asked ..

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I changed the case now nevertheless because PostgreSQL will translate it into lowercase anyways and because that's the commonly used style. TNX for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

**This is a SQL Server based solution, but the concept applies to most any RDBMS.**

Like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Rating (
    rid int NOT NULL,
    uid int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Rating PRIMARY KEY (rid, uid)
);

ALTER TABLE Rating ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Rating_Recipies FOREIGN KEY(rid)
    REFERENCES Recipies (rid);

ALTER TABLE Rating  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Rating_User FOREIGN KEY(uid)
   REFERENCES User (uid);
```

This ensures that the values inside of `Rating` are only **valid** values inside of both the `Users` table and the `Recipes` table.  Please note, in the `Rating` table I didn't include the other fields you had, just add those.

Assume in the users table you have 3 users: Joe, Bob and Bill respective ID's 1,2,3.  And in the recipes table you had cookies, chicken pot pie, and pumpkin pie respective ID's are 1,2,3.  Then inserting into Rating table will only allow for these values, the minute you enter 4 for a RID or a UID SQL throws an error and does not commit the transaction.

Try it yourself, its a good learning experience.

Comment: I took the liberty to convert you T-SQL syntax into the equivalent ANSI SQL that would work on PostgreSQL and most other DBMS (including SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

In Postgresql a correct way to implement these tables are:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE uid_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE rid_seq;

CREATE TABLE User(
  uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('uid_seq'),
  uname VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Recipes(
  rid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('rid_seq'),
  content VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Rating(
  rid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Recipes(rid),
  uid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES User(uid),
  rating INTEGER CHECK (0<=rating and rating<=5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(rid,uid)
);
```

There is no real difference between the two options that you have written.

Comment: You must review your knowledge of PostgreSQL. The clause REFERENCES makes a foreign key and, if the column is omitted, the column used is the primary key.

Comment: EDIT: deleted comment to which @doctore refers, I overlooked the `REFERENCES` clause in the second version of the OP and said there is a difference between the two versions. Of course there is none...

Comment: Your example misses out on the [serial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) data type and carries two redundant `NOT NULL` constraints in `Rating` - the primary key enforces those automatically. Both not wrong, but made @A.H.'s answer the clearly better one.

Answer (score 0):

A simple (i.e. single-column) foreign key may be declared in-line with the column declaration or not. It's merely a question of style. A third way should be to omit foreign key declarations from the `CREATE TABLE` entirely and later add them using `ALTER TABLE` statements; done in a transaction (presumable along with all the other tables, constraints, etc) the table would never exist without its required constraints. Choose whichever you think is easiest fora human coder to read and understand i.e. is easiest to maintain.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: I overlooked the `REFERENCES` clause in the second version when I wrote my original answer. The two versions are identical in terms of referential integrity, there are just two ways of syntax to do this.

Comment: Two versions are correct. You must see the CREATE TABLE web page of PostgreSQL documentation.

Comment: @doctore oops, I simply overlooked the `REFERENCES` clause in the second version, my bad. of course the two versions are identical in terms of referential integrity.