# Where to state a foreign key when creating a table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I would like to design a table named `arguments` whose an attribute `name` is linked to another attribute `name` in a table called `names`.

I see two ways to express it in SQL:

1. by creating a constraint on the table:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE names (   name text UNIQUE,
                         short text UNIQUE,
                       comment text);
   CREATE TABLE arguments (   name text UNIQUE,
                           comment text,
                           FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES names (name));
   ```
2. by qualifying the attribute on-the-fly:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE names (   name text UNIQUE,
                         short text UNIQUE,
                       comment text);
   CREATE TABLE arguments (   name text UNIQUE REFERENCES names (name),
                           comment text);
   ```

I would like to know:

- if one of the two is commonly known as better than the other, and
- if it can have consequences that I should be aware of.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL? SqlServer? etc?

Comment: Using text data as a key is a bad practice.  Your name table should have an ID column, this then becomes the FK for any references.

Comment: @cdeszaq I am using SQLite (for a proof of concept).

Comment: If this is just proof of concept, then it doesn't matter. Get the proof done, and then do the actual work. Don't waste time solving problems that don't exist _right now_.

Comment: @cdeszaq - Although the sentiment of "don't let things stop you just getting it done" has great merit, I would not use it as a reason to avoid good practice (such as keeping identifiers and data as separate entities).  Getting it done *as well as reasonably possible* can and does make life MUCH easier if and when you come to productionising the proof of concept.  PART of the proof-of-concept should often be the software architecture.

Comment: @Dems - I agree 100% with having a surrogate ID in _all_ cases, and that aspect of design _should_ be included in a proof-of-concept, but the issue at hand (how to declare a FK relationship) is not something that a PoC needs to even have on it's radar (in general).

Comment: We've had a couple of similar questions recently [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421055/correct-way-to-create-a-table-that-references-variables-from-another-table/8428298#8428298) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315628/what-is-foreign-key-is-for/8323581#8323581).

Comment: @onedaywhen Thanks for the links. It adds some details to the explanations I already got here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the first option is known as `out-of-line` constraint declaration and the second option is `in-line`, both of them are functionally same.

What would be better is to assign a name to the foreign key constraint. If you have a name, you can selectively enable and disable the constraint if required.

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE arguments 
(   
    name text UNIQUE,                         
    comment text,                         
    constraint arguments_fk FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES names (name)
);
```

Disable constraint

```
ALTER TABLE arguments NOCHECK CONSTRAINT arguments_fk;
```

Enable constraint

```
ALTER TABLE arguments CHECK CONSTRAINT arguments_fk;
```

This is for SQL Server. Oracle has equivalent commands.

Answer (score 2):

These are just different syntax for the same end result.

Either is appropriate, but the former is a more common style in my experience.  This may simply be to allow the human mind to more easily digest all the information.  First describe the data, second describe how it relates to the rest of the world.

One comment I would make though, is that is more common to have IDs as unique identifiers and references.  This allows you to change the Value in the Name field without changing it's Identity and breaking Referential Integrity.  There are databases that can cascade such changes and update all occurrences of the Name, but in general it's considered cleaner to have Identifiers that are Separate from the Data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreign key. If you later find you have a performance problem (a *measurable problem*), then you can change it up to be different.

Keep things simple at first and get the product into the users' hands as fast as possible. Don't optimize things that you can't prove need it.

Comment: Both of these Are examples for Foreign Key Relationships.